# Possible Lack of Rigor in Common Multivariable Chain Rule Expression?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to get my head around an issue with the multivariable chain rule as it's commonly written. By way of illustration, let's use this simple example, taken from [here](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c353.html) (about halfway down the page). $z$ is a bivariate function of $x,y$, ie $z=f(x,y)$. $y$ is also a function of $x$, ie $y=g(x)$.

Now, we have this expression for the total derivative, or chain rule: $$\frac{dz}{dx}= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}      (1)$$

The meaning of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ is the rate of change of $z$ when $y$ is varied but $x$ is held constant. But since $y=g(x)$ holds at the same time, this is impossible to do, because if $x$ is held constant, so must be $y$ - it's impossible to vary $y$ and for $y=g(x)$ to hold at the same time.

Of course, we know how to evaluate $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$: my way is to "pretend" that we don't know there is a dependence $y=g(x)$, and compute $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ as if $x$ and $y$ are independent.

So:
Is Equation $(1)$, in fact, not rigorous? Is $y$ and $x$ doing "double duty"? If so, I'm trying to figure out how to make it rigorous - can "dummy variables" be introduced to do this?

Comment: I might rather have written $$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is of course not rigorous. There are two functions mixed up here. One is

$$ f \, : \,\,(x_1,x_2) \mapsto f(x_1,x_2),$$

the other is

$$ z \, : \,\,x \mapsto f(x,g(x)).$$

So the statement $(1)$ should be like this:

$$\left.\frac{dz}{dx}\right\rvert_{x_0} = \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\right\rvert_{(x_0,g(x_0))} + \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\right\rvert_{(x_0,g(x_0))} \cdot \left.\frac{dg}{dx}\right\rvert_{x_0}  \qquad \cdots \quad    (1)$$

or, if you don't like the $x$ appearing all the time, like this :
$$\left.\frac{dz}{dx}\right\rvert_{x_0} = \left.\partial_1 f\right\rvert_{(x_0,g(x_0))} + \left.\partial_2 f\right\rvert_{(x_0,g(x_0))} \cdot \left.\frac{dg}{dx}\right\rvert_{x_0}  \qquad \cdots \quad    (1)$$

The notations $\partial_1 f$ and $\partial_2 f$ mean the partial derivatives of $f$ on the first and second variable.

Comment: Thanks for this corindo. I'll study it more carefully and let you know if I have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

We all have
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} 
+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt},$$
for any election of variables and dependences.

Now if we set $x=t$ we naturally get
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx} 
+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx},$$ 
which upon simplification gives
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx},$$
which is perfectly valid.

Comment: for an effective example please check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499336/the-derivative-of-a-function-of-a-variable-with-respect-to-a-function-of-the-sam/1499370#1499370

Comment: Thanks janmarqz. I'm reading the other question you linked to - will let you know of any comments or questions.