# Is it correct that the partial derivatives are defined only for functions whose domain is $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Recently, I've encountered this question about the chain rule [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810811/reconcile-the-chain-rule-with-a-derivative-formula). The OP asked that

> Let $F$ be a function of $x$ and $z$, and $z$ is a function of $x$. Then by the chain rule: $$\frac{dF}{dx} = \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}} + \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}$$ I'm not sure how the equation is derived.

In this question and the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2810840/368425) of the above question, the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}}$ appear. Moreover, the OP did not mention the domain and the codomain of $F$.

1. My textbook and [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Partial_derivative#/Formal_definition) only define partial derivatives when the domain of our function is $\mathbb R^n$. Is correct that the concept of partial derivatives is defined only for functions' the domain is $\mathbb R^n$?
2. Is it correct that the notations $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}}$ in the linked question only make sense when the domain of $F$ is $\mathbb R^n$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Applying the chain rule with Jacobian matrices might clear things up...

Comment: the domain can be open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Hi @CalvinKhor, the notion of partial derivative, which is a special case of directional derivative, is defined only for functions whose domain is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, right?

Comment: I would guess so if you want nice theorems to hold, but there's nothing stopping you from "partially differentiating" if the limit is well-defined. So maybe a function only defined on $\{(x,y):x=0\}$ should have partials in $y$ but not in $x$.

Comment: I got it @CalvinKhor. Thank you so much for your help!